# Google Apps Script : How to create database, schemas and tables?

Tags: database, google-apps-script

**How can I create a database ( with its tables and schemas..) in Google Apps Script?**  I have intention to query my database by **ScriptDb** for **my application deployed as web**. So is there any console option or graphical interface to create my database and the tables? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of creating a schema in Google Apps Script. Also, you don't have to 'create' a database. Every script already has one which you can access using

```
ScriptDb.getMyDb()
```

This DB is not a traditional relational database but instead is better described as a 'Javascript object store'. So, if you want to add a 'record', just create a Javascript object with all the columns and add it to the database.
For example, your javascript object could be something like

```
var student = { 'name' : 'Adam',
                'Address' : ' Whatever address here',
                'Age' : 20,
              }
```

Read [this piece of documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb) for more information

Comment: Yes, I was on this page before asking my question. But does this mean that I am obliged to use MySQL or Oracle to have my Schema and tables? What about the getter getMyDb(), does it mean that I am right only of one database? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also, you have one DB per script. So, each script you write has its own database. 
This may or may not be relevant but you can use Apps Script to connect to a MySQL database too.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the ScriptDB service no longer exists.  :-(  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/sunset